# PHPMailer & Form to Database

Tags: php, phpmailer

hey so i've been trying to send a mail to person who filled the form on my website,
but im new to programming and i get the error of 500 when i run the code below. Or are there any other ways of sending email to form filler automaticly

```
if (isset($_POST['gp_save_idelegateadd_onsite']))   {


*use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
$lastname = $_GET['gp_applicant_lastname'];
$email = $_GET['gp_applicant_mail'];
/* creates object */
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mailid = $email;
$subject = "GOMailer - Regarding your ESMUN 2020 application.";
$text_message = "Hello";
$message = "Dear $lastname , your application is recieved to be reviewed.";
try {
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = "mail.gelecekodakliakademi.com";
    $mail->Port = '587';
    $mail->AddAddress($mailid);
    $mail->Username ="system@gelecekodakliakademi.com";
    $mail->Password ="-----]";
    $mail->SetFrom('system@gelecekodakliakademi.com','NoReply_GOMailer');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("system@gelecekodakliakademi.com","NoReply_GOMailer");
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = $message;
    if($mail->Send()) { echo "Thank you for register u got a notification through the mail you provide"; } }
    catch(phpmailerException $ex)
    { $msg = " ".$ex->errorMessage()." "; }*

    // Form to Database
    $addconfig=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO applications SET
        gp_applicant_name = :gp_applicant_name,
        gp_applicant_lastname = :gp_applicant_lastname,
        gp_applicant_birthdate = :gp_applicant_birthdate,
        gp_applicant_mail = :gp_applicant_mail,
        gp_applicant_gender = :gp_applicant_gender,
        gp_applicant_city = :gp_applicant_city,
        gp_applicant_gsm = :gp_applicant_gsm,
        gp_applicant_school = :gp_applicant_school,
        gp_applicant_faculty = :gp_applicant_faculty,
        gp_applicant_munrel = :gp_applicant_munrel,
        gp_applicant_munrellist = :gp_applicant_munrellist,
        gp_applicant_pref1 = :gp_applicant_pref1,
        gp_applicant_pref2 = :gp_applicant_pref2,
        gp_applicant_pref3 = :gp_applicant_pref3,
        gp_applicant_letter = :gp_applicant_letter,
        gp_applicant_condition = :gp_applicant_condition,
        gp_applicant_what = :gp_applicant_what,
        gp_applicant_status = :gp_applicant_status ");

    $insert=$addconfig->execute(array(
        'gp_applicant_name' => $_POST['gp_applicant_name'],
        'gp_applicant_lastname' => $_POST['gp_applicant_lastname'],
        'gp_applicant_birthdate' => $_POST['gp_applicant_birthdate'],
        'gp_applicant_mail' => $_POST['gp_applicant_mail'],
        'gp_applicant_gender' => $_POST['gp_applicant_gender'],
        'gp_applicant_city' => $_POST['gp_applicant_city'],
        'gp_applicant_gsm' => $_POST['gp_applicant_gsm'],
        'gp_applicant_school' => $_POST['gp_applicant_school'],
        'gp_applicant_faculty' => $_POST['gp_applicant_faculty'],
        'gp_applicant_munrel' => $_POST['gp_applicant_munrel'],
        'gp_applicant_munrellist' => $_POST['gp_applicant_munrellist'],
        'gp_applicant_pref1' => $_POST['gp_applicant_pref1'],
        'gp_applicant_pref2' => $_POST['gp_applicant_pref2'],
        'gp_applicant_pref3' => $_POST['gp_applicant_pref3'],
        'gp_applicant_letter' => $_POST['gp_applicant_letter'],
        'gp_applicant_condition' => $_POST['gp_applicant_condition'],
        'gp_applicant_what' => $_POST['gp_applicant_what'],
        'gp_applicant_status' => $_POST['gp_applicant_status'] ));

        // Feedback
    if ($insert) {
        header("Location:../../../apply.php?view=delegate&apply=ok");
    } else {
        header("Location:../../../apply.php?view=delegate&apply=err");
    }

}
```

the part

```
*use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
$lastname = $_GET['gp_applicant_lastname'];
$email = $_GET['gp_applicant_mail'];
/* creates object */
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mailid = $email;
$subject = "GOMailer - Regarding your ESMUN 2020 application.";
$text_message = "Hello";
$message = "Dear $lastname , your application is recieved to be reviewed.";
try {
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = "mail.gelecekodakliakademi.com";
    $mail->Port = '587';
    $mail->AddAddress($mailid);
    $mail->Username ="system@gelecekodakliakademi.com";
    $mail->Password ="-----]";
    $mail->SetFrom('system@gelecekodakliakademi.com','NoReply_GOMailer');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("system@gelecekodakliakademi.com","NoReply_GOMailer");
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = $message;
    if($mail->Send()) { echo "Thank you for register u got a notification through the mail you provide"; } }
    catch(phpmailerException $ex)
    { $msg = " ".$ex->errorMessage()." "; }*
```

I belive what caused the error cuz when I remove it, form goes to database without issue, thank you.

Comment: Anyway the first step would be to check your error log. But I notice that there are asterisks at `*use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` and `{ $msg = " ".$ex->errorMessage()." "; }*` ? By any chance did you uncommented it and forgot to remove the asterisks ?

Comment: @YTZ there is no asterisks in my code its there because i've formatted it wrong on post editor, sorry for that

Comment: A 500 is a server error; check your logs and/or enable error reporting.